# Duvida em vetor em c

Tags: c, lógica

Criar uma função contador que funciona da seguinte forma:

- o valor inicial do contador é 5.
- toda vez que a função for chamada o contador dela deve ser diminuído.
- o contador   deve   se   reinicializar   automaticamente:   quando   o contador chegar em 0, na próxima chamada da função o contador deve ser reinicializado com 5 de novo.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
static int contador = 5;

void cont();

int main(){
        cont();
        return 0;
}

void cont(){
        int i,j=0;
        int vet[contador];
        do{
                for(i = 1;i <= contador;i++){
                        vet[i]++;
                        printf("%d\n",vet[i]);
                }
                contador -=1;
        }while(contador != 0);

}
```

Comment: Eae cara, vc poderia explicitar sua dúvida?

Comment: Estou com duvida na parte de implementar um vetor e quando o contador deve se reinicializar automaticamente quando o contador chegar em 0.

Comment: Sua questão não fala nada de vetor, aonde entra um vetor no que deseja?

Comment: então e sotirar o vetor e considerar que minha duvida e     o contador deve se reinicializar automaticamente: quando o contador chegar em 0, na próxima chamada da função o contador deve ser reinicializado com 5 de novo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há um problema na sua função, ela acessa uma posição de memória inválida. Em C os índices de um vetor vão de 0 a N-1. No seu caso o vetor vai de `v[0]` a `v[4]`, precisa corrigir isso no loop.

Para fazer o contador reiniciar para 5 basta colocar um `if` no final do loop. Perceba que com isso seu programa vai entrar em loop infinito, uma vez que contador sempre será diferente de 0 quando for avaliado no `do{}while()`. Segue a alteração abaixo:

```
void cont(){
        int i;
        int vet[contador];
        do{
                for(i = 0; i < contador; i++)
                {
                        vet[i]++;
                        printf("%d\n",vet[i]);
                }
                contador -=1;
                if (contador == 0)
                    contador = 5;
        }while(contador != 0);
}
```

Comment: O `if` deve ir fora do `do-while`, caso contrario o `loop` será infinto, pois sempre que chegar ao fim, o valor de `contador` voltará a ser `5` e a condição `contador != 0` nunca será satisfeita.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que pude entender, tu quer fazer um contador regressivo de quantas vezes esta função foi chamada, chegando no valor 0 (zero) ele retorna ao valor inicial.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 3

int GLOBAL_COUNT = MAX;

void contador();

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        contador();
    }
    return 0;
}

void contador() {
    if (GLOBAL_COUNT <= 0) {
        GLOBAL_COUNT = MAX;
    }
    printf("chamada: %d/%d\n", GLOBAL_COUNT, MAX);
    GLOBAL_COUNT--;
}
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0YDQod).

Neste meu exemplo eu tomei a liberdade de mudar o valor para `3` apenas para simplificar a visualização e apenas isso, nele eu criei um valor constante `MAX` e atribui a uma variável que é o contador global de repetições, esta vai ser decrementada na chamada da função.

No **main** eu fiz um `loop` de `7` chamadas para mostrar o cotador funcionando.

Em **contador()** ele esta comparando se o valor atual de `GLOBAL_COUNT` é menor ou igual a `0` (zero), caso seja, então ele reinicia o valor, após isso ele vai printar o valor atual e depois vai fazer o decremento informando que passou pela função.